# How can i change text vibration on my Galaxy S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sms, notifications, vibration

I want to change sms vibrations on my Galaxy S3 but I can only change it for incoming calls.
Can someone tell how to change notification vibrations for sms on my Samsung Galaxy S3?

Thank you in advance.

PS : I am using Hangouts.

Edit : If possible, I don't want to install an app to solve my problem.

Comment: I have answered, but I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'change' the vibration, I've given the answer to disable/enable them. As for changing the duration, type etc you can't unless rooted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android each application can control the notifications itself. So if you turn off vibration for calls, texts will still have the option, and so on.

In the case of Hangouts:

- Open the application.
- Swipe from the left to open the menu (technically it's a [navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)).
- Tap "`Settings`"
- Tap "`SMS`"

You can enable/disable vibration here:

[image]
<sub>(source: [techcovered.org](http://img.techcovered.org/tc/Hangouts-SMS-settings.png))</sub>

If you wish to change the intensity/duration/pattern of the vibration you either need an SMS app that supports this feature or [root](/questions/tagged/root) access to your device coupled with a custom kernel that allows this feature.

Alternatively (though you specified you don't want to) you could try an app like [Vibrate tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dfs) and see if that fits your need. I have not tested this app.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. So you are telling me that whithout a specific application or using a custom kernel it is impossible? edit : I am talking about intensity/duration/pattern of the vibrations.

Comment: @Maxime as far as I know yes. I'll keep looking for you though, but as of now the only way I can find is using S-Tweaks or something similar to change kernel settings.

Comment: I will try it, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @Maxime no problem, happy to help! I've added a link to an app that might help. I know you don't want to install one, but it might be the way to go in this case.